# How to obtain rainbow chips?

Tags: cookie-clicker-collector

In Cookie Clicker Collector, you go to the settings button and see this: 
[image]

How do I get rainbow chips in the first place? What can they be used for?

Comment: I take it this is yet another mobile clone?

Comment: What happens if you press the big question mark next to where it says "Rainbow Chips"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Heavenly_Chips . 
Basically when you reset with a lot of cookies you get them and they boost your CpS.

Comment: You ARE aware that cookie clicker the browser game has absolutely no relation to this one, right?  It's a pure knockoff, and there's no guarantee the gameplay will exactly match.

Comment: Yes. I said that they "look like" heavenly chips.

Comment: So what guarantee is there that these rainbow chips are going to work like heavenly chips?  Just because they look similar doesn't mean they'll work the same.

Comment: I never said that there was a guarantee that they would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rainbow Chips message in-game]
<sup>Click for larger version.</sup>

> **Prestige**
> Restart the game and earn Rainbow Chips. The more lifetime cookies you've collected, the more Rainbow Chips you'll get. If you prestige now, you'll have a TOTAL of:
>
> 0 Rainbow Chips

This is how you get them.

If you go to the Plus, you can spend them for really good boosts, as well as if you just have one then it will give you a CPS boost.

Comment: You should put  the text in the image in your post. Don't just post an image